# php fopen ssh2 sftp connection result "Resource id #5"

Tags: php, sftp, ssh2

By using followign code i get the result "Resource id #5" if I echo $stream

I use PHP 7.0 on apache (linux) phpinfo:

- **ssh2**
- extension version    0.12+dev
- libssh2 version  1.5.0
- banner   SSH-2.0-libssh2_1.5.0*

  ```
  <?php
  // $server = ... etc.
  $connection = ssh2_connect($server, $port);   
  ssh2_auth_password($connection, $username, $password); 
  $sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);

  $filename = 'test.csv';

  $stream = fopen("ssh2.sftp://" . intval($sftp) . "/dir/$filename", 'r'); 
  echo $stream; // Result: "Resource id #5"
  ?>
  ```

The result is "Resource id #5" and I don't know what I do wrong

Comment: Not sure what part you think is wrong? Looks expected to me.

Comment: I want to get the content of CSV file but I get the result in browser "Ressource id #5" but i don't know why

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+php%20Resource%20id%20#3

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to read the file you will have to do a fread() on the $stream. You can't just echo the result of a fopen.

Comment: $contents = fread($stream, filesize($remoteFile));
fclose($stream);  Result: filesize(): stat failed for /dir/test.csv

Comment: There's actually a remote version of fread, I wanted you to go look at the PHP manual: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php. The function you're looking for is: $contents = stream_get_contents($handle);
fclose($handle);

Comment: fgets() helped me, fread no way...